# Question regarding supremum of partially ordered sets

Tags: discrete-mathematics, supremum-and-infimum

I have encountered a question while I was practicing the topic 'upper and lower bound of partially ordered sets'.

> Let $\mathbb{Q}$ be the set of rational numbers.  Let
>
> $$
> B = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : x < \sqrt[3]{3} \}  
> $$
> Prove that $\sup{B}$ and $\inf{B}$ does not exists.

Here is my proof  to prove that $\sup{B}$ does not exists -

Let $r$ be any upper bound of  $B$.
Then $r$ is a rational number hence $r\not=\sqrt[3]3$

But there always exists
$p \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $\sqrt[3]3 < p < r$  as $\displaystyle\lim_{m\to\infty}(r-\frac1m)=r$, hence for all large enough $m$ we have $\displaystyle\sqrt[3]3<r-\frac1m<r$ and we can take $\displaystyle p=r-\frac1m$ for some $m$.

Hence $r$ is an upper bound of $B$ but not the least one proving that  $\sup{B}$ does not exists.
$■$

How can we prove that $\sup{B}$ does not exists?

Can there exist a more formal proof ?

A detailed answer would be helpful.

Comment: How do you get $\sqrt[3]3<z$?

Comment: As @LordSharktheUnknown notes, your proof is wrong. You cannot conclude that $3^{1/3} < z$. This is simply not true.

Comment: @EpsilonDelta You can, in fact, conclude that $\sqrt[3]{3}<z$. Actually, you can conclude anything you want, since a contradictory assumption was made when it was assumed that $z=\sup B$ (together with $z\in\mathbb{Q}$). The problem is that the derivation of $\sqrt[3]{3}<z$ is missing.

Comment: Yes, you are right.

Comment: @Aditya: No, you still  do not justify that $z$ will be greater than $\sqrt[3]{3}$. You also do not prove the existence of $p$.

Comment: @Arturo Magidin: Well, $z < \sqrt[3]3$ as z = $\sup{B}$ which is an upper bound of  $B$ and preceeds every other upper bound of  $B$. Since the binary relation on $\mathbb{Q}$ is not mentioned, so we assume the relation to be '$<$'

Comment: Oh, I have no problem concluding that $z\lt \sqrt[3]{3}$ (well, rather, first that $z\leq \sqrt[3]{3}$, then that it is not equal to it). *But that's not what you do*. You instead assert $\sqrt[3]{3}\lt z$. Your final sentence seems, to me, to be a non sequitur apropos of nothing. Also, all of your statements of the form $\forall x\in B\lt \sqrt[3]{3}$ are ungrammatical as written. The formula "$\forall x\in B$" is not less than anything. Read it out loud to see why it makes no sense as written (Yes, I know what you *mean* to say, but that is not what you are saying).

Comment: I have edited my proof. Is it valid now ?

Comment: Better, but you should say *somewhere* that $r$ is rational. Since you are invoking $\sqrt[3]{3}$, which is not in $\mathbb{Q}$, you are implicitly allowing for the fact that real numbers exist, and so you need to exclude them explicitly (also, $B$ has no supremum *in $\mathbb{Q}$*, but it certainly has one in $\mathbb{R}$). Alternatively, you should be talking about the rationals $q$ that are either negative or satisfy $q^3\leq 3$, if you don't want to allude to nonrational reals.

Comment: How can it be proved formally that lower bound of $B $ does not exists though i have proved it intuitively ?

Comment: I don’t do chat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $r$ be an irrational number,
$B = \{ x \in \mathbb{Q} : x < r \}$ and
${q_n}$ a sequence within $B$ that converges to $r$.

Let $b$ be, within $\mathbb{Q}$, the least upper bound of $B$.
If $b < r$, then exists $n$ in $N$ with $b < q_n$.
So r < b.
Let $\left\{p_n\right\}$ be a sequence rationals $> r$ that converges to $r$.
Thus some $n$ in $N$ with $p_n < b$.
As $p_n$ is an upper bound of $B$, a contradiction ensues.

Thusforth one concludes within the rationals that $\sup B$ is fantasy.

How to generate the sequences.
Since Q is a dense subset of R, every not empty open set will contain a rational.
Whence for all n in N, there is a rational $q_n$ in (r-1/n, r).

Comment: Can i be explained that which kind of sequence is being referred by $q_n$ and $p_n$ and why do they converge to $r $?

Comment: @Aditya.  See edit and spell 'I' correctly.

Comment: Please explain that which kind of sequence is being referred by $q_n$ and $p_n$ and why do they converge to $r$?